# Is EU hosted Azure data safe from the patriot act?

Tags: security, azure

I read recently some news about how MS will have to hand over data to the US government if they asked for it. ( http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/07/04/eu_customer_cloud_data_may_be_handed_over_by_microsoft/ or http://yro.slashdot.org/story/11/07/05/1840243/Patriot-Act-vs-the-EUs-Data-Protection-Directive )

Some of our clients could be concerned by that.

MS does have european datacenters, but i was wondering if anyone knew if these datacenter could be targeted too ?

Comment: You really do need to get your company lawyer to answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft already admitted that it must comply and hand over the data if required.  Any company that does business in the US or had assets in the US that could be seized or frozen can be compelled to hand over data, regardless of where the data resides.

Additionally, the company hosting the data may be prohibited from disclosing that it was required to hand over the data.